# caching for huge database

Tags: php, mysql, database, caching, hosting

i am working on a project which is a kind of social network ... studies said that we'll have the first couple of months more than 100,000 users.

the website is done using php mysql and i am searching for the fastest caching engine, since we are talking about caching user data after he sign in.

so we are talking about a huge database, huge records in same table, huge number of users and requests, huge size of caching.

please note that as first step, the website should be hosted on shared server before it will gonna be moved to dedicated server ( it's the client decision, not our)

any tip, hint or suggestion is appreciated.
thanks

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to ask a specific question in order to get much help on this.

Comment: what do you want to cache? Do you have queries that you think will slow the response a lot?

Comment: What types of data will you be storing, chat messages, postings, statuses, etc? What are acceptable delays?

Comment: There are studies for predicting social network user growth? Heh. "1 * unknown = users"

Comment: i need to cache data such as ( blogs ids, comments ids, info ids, ...) and the delay should be as long he is online

Comment: I don't quite get your caching strategy... why cache a user's blog ids, comment ids, etc while he's online?  Are you trying to reduce latency for each user?  I was assuming you wanted to use caching to reduce the overall resource load of your application... which will help reduce latency... ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Put a lot of thought into a sensible database schema, since changing it later will be painful.  MySQL tables are good for doing fast SELECT operations, which sounds appropriate for your app.

2) Don't optimize your code prematurely, ie don't worry about a caching solution yet, instead focus on writing modular code so you can easily improve bottlenecks with caching later.

3) After 1 and 2, you need to think about caching based on what will retrieved and how often.  I've seen applications that put user information into the session variable - that will reduce database hits.  If that's not sufficent, look into Memcached.  If you have bigger data, maybe Varnish.

Comment: once we start talking about memcached we need a dedicated server and as our first step is a shared server, we are out of this option.
Do you have any idea about Alternative Php Cache (APC) or any similar chache layer?

Comment: Why do you need a dedicated server for memcached?  I've run php/mysql/memcached on a vps.

Comment: @mr.x - how do you plan to support 100,000 users on a shared server?

Comment: interesting point, i'll gonna take it in consideration. thanks

Comment: @Ericpetroelje as soon as it start growing it will be moved to dedicated server.
I ment the network will grow quickly and of course it wont still on the shared server till 100, 000 ( i already noticed that its the client decision, if it is back to me i wont do it)